# Git Integration with phpDesigner 8

Tags: php, git, phpdesigner

I installed phpDesigner 8 and Git but phpDesigner say "git not found". I also attachet it in settings / integration / SVN+GIT -> C:\Program Files\Git\Git Bash.vbs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Settings / integration / SVN/GIT you should point at the git.exe file.
It's located in your GIT bin folder (\Git\bin\git.exe).

Answer (score 1):

Actually, in phpDesigner 8 it's Tools -> Preferences -> Integrations -> TortoiseSVN+Git -> Git.

Answer (score 1):

You can find your Git executable in the following directory

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_<numbersandletters>\bin\git.exe
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

Try connect to PhpDesigner (it's Tools -> Preferences -> Integrations -> TortoiseSVN+Git -> Git.) with input this link file :

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe
```